# I want to run a FOR inside an IF statment to concatenate using & in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

This is my first time using VBA. I am generating data in a grid of cells by any number of rows and a fixed 4 columns. Please note that the rows are not fixed, so for example the data may be in a grid from B17 to E20 (4x4 grid) or it also change to B17 to E25 (4x9 grid).

[image: screenshot]

Now, not all entries in the grid will contain data, some will remain blank.

So my problem is I want to list all of the entries in the grid in one cell on excel separated by ";"

I think I will need to use logic statements to omit the blank cells, but I do not how to use them with strings and also because the number of rows will change, I will need to put all of it inside a loop. Yet as soon as I do that and try to generate content into one excel using the & operator, the content gets overwritten.

Please see code below for the full macro and an attached screenshot of the data you will need to enter in the grey cells to make it work.

My post is referring to the "Images in Website Gallery" section...

```
Sub Combo()
'
' Combo Colours Sizes
'

    MaxColours = Range("f3")
    MaxSizes = Range("h3")
    RowOffset = 3
    Col1 = 1
    Col2 = 7
    Col3 = 9
    Col4 = 10
    Col5 = 12
    Col6 = 13
    CurRow = 4

'   Generate Simple Images for all Colours and Sizes

    For I = 1 To MaxColours
        For J = 1 To MaxSizes

            Cells(CurRow, Col3).Value = Cells(RowOffset + I, Col1).Value
            Cells(CurRow, Col4).Value = Cells(RowOffset + J, Col2).Value
            Cells(CurRow, Col5) = Range("f1") & "-" & Cells(CurRow, Col3).Value & "-" & Cells(CurRow, Col4).Value

            UpperColour = Cells(RowOffset + I, Col1)
            LowerColour = LCase(UpperColour)

                For K = 0 To 3
                    Cells(CurRow, Col6 + K) = "/" & LowerColour & "c.jpg"
                Next K

            CurRow = CurRow + 1
        Next J
    Next I

    Cells(CurRow, Col5).Value = Range("f1")
    Cells(CurRow + 1, Col5).Value = Range("f1") & "-M"

    CurRowTwo = 4

'   Generate Available Images

    For N = 1 To MaxColours
        For O = 1 To 4

            Colour = Cells(RowOffset + N, Col1)
            Image = Cells(RowOffset + N, Col1 + O)
            If Image <> "" Then
            Cells(CurRowTwo + N + 12, Col1 + O).Value = "/" & LCase(Colour) & LCase(Image) & ".jpg"
            Else
            Cells(CurRowTwo + N + 12, Col1 + O).Value = ""
            End If

        Next O
    Next N

'   Website Config
'   Images in first 3 columns

    For L = 1 To 3
        Cells(CurRow, Col5 + L) = "/" & Range("h17")
    Next L

'   Images in Website Media Gallery

    CurRowTwo = 4

            Cells(CurRow, Col5 + 4).Value = Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 9, Col1 + 1) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 9, Col1 + 2) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 9, Col1 + 3) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 9, Col1 + 4) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 10, Col1 + 1) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 10, Col1 + 2) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 10, Col1 + 3) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 10, Col1 + 4) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 11, Col1 + 4) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 11, Col1 + 4) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 11, Col1 + 4) & "; " & Cells(CurRowTwo + MaxColours + 11, Col1 + 4)


'   Marketplace Config
'   Images in first 3 columns

    For M = 1 To 3
        Cells(CurRow + 1, Col5 + M) = "/" & Range("h19")
    Next M

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the `concatenate` function won't do this?

Comment: You can identify blanks several ways... `cell.value = vbNullString` or `cell.value = ""` or `len(cell.Value) = 0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are trying to achieve but, from what I understood, here is a small snippet that should do the trick.

```
'Define your grid area
firstRowOfGrid = 17
lastRowOfGrid = 29
numberOfCols = 4
firstColLetter = "B"

cellValue = ""                  'This one will hold the cell value
concatenatedString = ""         'This will be the concatenated string

firstColLetter = Asc(firstColLetter)    'Convert the letter to a number

For j = firstColLetter To firstColLetter + numberOfCols     'Loop through the columns
    For i = firstRowOfGrid To lastRowOfGrid                 'Loop through the rows
        cellValue = Range(Chr(j) & i).Value                 'Get the current cell value
        If (cellValue) Then                                 'Check if current cell has a value
            'The new value of the concatenated string is the concatenated string itself followed by a semi-colon and the current
            'cell value
            concatenatedString = concatenatedString & ";" & cellValue
        End If
    Next i
Next j

'Remove the first semi-colon
concatenatedString = Mid(concatenatedString, 2, Len(concatenatedString))
'Do something with your string (currently displaying in a msgbox)
MsgBox concatenatedString
```

This code will loop through the fields B17 to E29 and add the cell value (if the cell is not empty) to a concatenated string that you can use later.